Why am I not getting NMEA output in RTKLib despite providing all required RTCM data?
I am working on an RTK-based positioning system, and I’ve encountered an issue while using RTK Navi software with RTCM data. Here’s a brief overview of what I’m doing and the issue I'm facing:
Workflow:
1.Raw Signal File: I have a raw GNSS signal file from this source
2.Conversion to RTCM: I’ve used GNSS-SDR to process and convert this raw GNSS signal to RTCM data.
3.RTK Navi Configuration: I’m sending this RTCM data to RTK Navi (in rover mode) via a TCP server stream in single positioning mode.
RTCM Data Breakdown:
The RTCM message contains:
1019 Message: GPS ephemeris data
1077 Message: MSM (Multiple Signal Messages) which contains satellite observations
Logs from RTK Navi:
Despite having both ephemeris data (from the 1019 message) and observation data (from the 1077 message),
I’m seeing the following logs in RTK Navi:
3 outsolheads:
3     0.102: rtksvrthread:
3 decode_rtcm3: len= 64 type=1019
3 outsolexs:
3 outnmea_gsa:
3 outnmea_gsv:
3 outsolexs:
3 decode_rtcm3: len= 64 type=1019
3 decode_rtcm3: len= 64 type=1019
3 outsolexs:
3 outnmea_gsa:
3 outnmea_gsv:
3 outsolexs:
3 decode_rtcm3: len= 98 type=1077
3 rtcm3 1077: signals=L1C
3 sortobs: nobs=5
3 rtkpos  : time=2024/11/28 06:24:06.180 n=5
3 pntpos  : tobs=2024/11/28 06:24:06.180 n=5
3 satposs : teph=2024/11/28 06:24:06.180 n=5 ephopt=0
2 no broadcast ephemeris: 2024/11/28 06:24:06 sat= 1 iode= -1
3 no broadcast clock 2024/11/28 06:24:06.102 sat= 1
2 no broadcast ephemeris: 2024/11/28 06:24:06 sat=11 iode= -1
3 no broadcast clock 2024/11/28 06:24:06.098 sat=11
2 no broadcast ephemeris: 2024/11/28 06:24:06 sat=17 iode= -1
3 no broadcast clock 2024/11/28 06:24:06.097 sat=17
2 no broadcast ephemeris: 2024/11/28 06:24:06 sat=20 iode= -1
3 no broadcast clock 2024/11/28 06:24:06.104 sat=20
2 no broadcast ephemeris: 2024/11/28 06:24:06 sat=32 iode= -1
3 no broadcast clock 2024/11/28 06:24:06.100 sat=32
3 estpos  : n=5
3 rescode: rr=0.000 0.000 0.000
2 06:24:06.18: point pos error (lack of valid sats ns=6)

The log suggests that no broadcast ephemeris data is being received for certain satellites (e.g., sat=1, sat=11, sat=17, etc.), which might be causing issues with the position calculation.
The point position error indicates a lack of valid satellites, despite having satellite observations.
I have parsed the RTCM message and confirmed that the data contains the GPS ephemeris (1019) and satellite observations (1077),following is the output:
RTCM Message: <RTCM(1019, DF002=1019, DF009=1, DF076=710, DF077=0, DF078=1, DF079=1.0618350643198937e-10, DF071=11, DF081=374400, DF082=0.0, DF083=3.410605131648481e-12, DF084=1.3121869415044785e-05, DF085=11, DF086=11.65625, DF087=1.4932766134734266e-09, DF088=0.9255710016004741, DF089=6.370246410369873e-07, DF090=0.00170298689045012, DF091=1.0170042514801025e-05, DF092=5153.699285507202, DF093=374400, DF094=-3.725290298461914e-08, DF095=-0.14744636742398143, DF096=2.9802322387695312e-08, DF097=0.30571883637458086, DF098=182.375, DF099=0.1000293861143291, DF100=-2.5420376914553344e-09, DF101=8.381903171539307e-09, DF102=0, DF103=0, DF137=0)>
RTCM Message: <RTCM(1019, DF002=1019, DF009=11, DF076=710, DF077=0, DF078=1, DF079=8.265033102361485e-11, DF071=23, DF081=374400, DF082=0.0, DF083=-3.637978807091713e-12, DF084=-0.00036899372935295105, DF085=23, DF086=-16.03125, DF087=1.94938820641255e-09, DF088=0.805243568494916, DF089=-9.51811671257019e-07, DF090=0.013865918037481606, DF091=1.0419636964797974e-05, DF092=5153.68804359436, DF093=374400, DF094=6.891787052154541e-08, DF095=-0.2406930923461914, DF096=-1.471489667892456e-07, DF097=0.28292631451040506, DF098=136.46875, DF099=0.3675759476609528, DF100=-2.709725777094718e-09, DF101=-1.1641532182693481e-08, DF102=0, DF103=0, DF137=0)>
RTCM Message: <RTCM(1019, DF002=1019, DF009=17, DF076=710, DF077=0, DF078=1, DF079=-4.433786671143025e-12, DF071=51, DF081=374400, DF082=0.0, DF083=-3.979039320256561e-12, DF084=3.3434946089982986e-05, DF085=51, DF086=-89.75, DF087=1.4347278920467943e-09, DF088=-0.38748728623613715, DF089=-4.474073648452759e-06, DF090=0.008297761552967131, DF091=8.987262845039368e-06, DF092=5153.6119022369385, DF093=374400, DF094=1.6391277313232422e-07, DF095=-0.4685374484397471, DF096=1.2293457984924316e-07, DF097=0.30708272382616997, DF098=206.5625, DF099=-0.7009897669777274, DF100=-2.5610233933548443e-09, DF101=-1.0244548320770264e-08, DF102=0, DF103=0, DF137=0)>
RTCM Message: <RTCM(1019, DF002=1019, DF009=20, DF076=710, DF077=0, DF078=1, DF079=-4.6838977141305804e-11, DF071=27, DF081=374400, DF082=0.0, DF083=1.8189894035458565e-12, DF084=9.131105616688728e-05, DF085=27, DF086=16.65625, DF087=1.7978436517296359e-09, DF088=0.26628841180354357, DF089=8.326023817062378e-07, DF090=0.005512800998985767, DF091=6.329268217086792e-06, DF092=5153.763521194458, DF093=374400, DF094=-8.940696716308594e-08, DF095=0.1690492695197463, DF096=2.7939677238464355e-08, DF097=0.2955873617902398, DF098=240.375, DF099=0.4128501187078655, DF100=-2.769866114249453e-09, DF101=-7.916241884231567e-09, DF102=0, DF103=0, DF137=0)>
RTCM Message: <RTCM(1019, DF002=1019, DF009=32, DF076=710, DF077=0, DF078=1, DF079=-7.526068657170981e-11, DF071=35, DF081=374400, DF082=0.0, DF083=-2.6147972675971687e-12, DF084=-0.0005480200052261353, DF085=35, DF086=14.5, DF087=1.585817699378822e-09, DF088=0.9003039402887225, DF089=7.078051567077637e-07, DF090=0.011573668685741723, DF091=6.686896085739136e-06, DF092=5153.7204875946045, DF093=374400, DF094=-1.564621925354004e-07, DF095=0.21318546682596207, DF096=1.695007085800171e-07, DF097=0.3023187732324004, DF098=243.8125, DF099=-0.12013805005699396, DF100=-2.5914914658642374e-09, DF101=-3.259629011154175e-09, DF102=0, DF103=0, DF137=0)>
RTCM Message: <RTCM(1077, DF002=1077, DF003=1234, DF004=368646180, DF393=0, DF409=0, DF001_7=0, DF411=0, DF412=0, DF417=0, DF418=0, DF394=9232537570078883840, NSat=5, DF395=1073741824, NSig=1, DF396=31, NCell=5, PRN_01=001, PRN_02=011, PRN_03=017, PRN_04=020, PRN_05=032, DF397_01=77, DF397_02=81, DF397_03=82, DF397_04=76, DF397_05=79, ExtSatInfo_01=0, ExtSatInfo_02=0, ExtSatInfo_03=0, ExtSatInfo_04=0, ExtSatInfo_05=0, DF398_01=0.8046875, DF398_02=0.9404296875, DF398_03=0.8291015625, DF398_04=0.0859375, DF398_05=0.748046875, DF399_01=-1327, DF399_02=-1019, DF399_03=-1871, DF399_04=-1566, DF399_05=-1206, CELLPRN_01=001, CELLSIG_01=1C, CELLPRN_02=011, CELLSIG_02=1C, CELLPRN_03=017, CELLSIG_03=1C, CELLPRN_04=020, CELLSIG_04=1C, CELLPRN_05=032, CELLSIG_05=1C, DF405_01=-0.00018352270126342773, DF405_02=-0.0002682805061340332, DF405_03=0.0004801154136657715, DF405_04=-9.679794311523438e-05, DF405_05=-0.0003514289855957031, DF406_01=-8.568167686462402e-08, DF406_02=1.1455267667770386e-07, DF406_03=-2.7474015951156616e-07, DF406_04=-8.055940270423889e-08, DF406_05=2.0302832126617432e-07, DF407_01=0, DF407_02=0, DF407_03=0, DF407_04=0, DF407_05=0, DF420_01=0, DF420_02=0, DF420_03=0, DF420_04=0, DF420_05=0, DF408_01=48.25, DF408_02=45.75, DF408_03=45.5625, DF408_04=44.125, DF408_05=46.6875, DF404_01=0.0502, DF404_02=-0.2672, DF404_03=-0.399, DF404_04=-0.2899, DF404_05=0.2154)>
RTCM Message: <RTCM(1077, DF002=1077, DF003=1234, DF004=368647000, DF393=0, DF409=0, DF001_7=0, DF411=0, DF412=0, DF417=0, DF418=0, DF394=9232537570078883840, NSat=5, DF395=1073741824, NSig=1, DF396=31, NCell=5, PRN_01=001, PRN_02=011, PRN_03=017, PRN_04=020, PRN_05=032, DF397_01=77, DF397_02=81, DF397_03=82, DF397_04=76, DF397_05=79, ExtSatInfo_01=0, ExtSatInfo_02=0, ExtSatInfo_03=0, ExtSatInfo_04=0, ExtSatInfo_05=0, DF398_01=0.80078125, DF398_02=0.9375, DF398_03=0.82421875, DF398_04=0.08203125, DF398_05=0.744140625, DF399_01=-1326, DF399_02=-1021, DF399_03=-1872, DF399_04=-1567, DF399_05=-1206, CELLPRN_01=001, CELLSIG_01=1C, CELLPRN_02=011, CELLSIG_02=1C, CELLPRN_03=017, CELLSIG_03=1C, CELLPRN_04=020, CELLSIG_04=1C, CELLPRN_05=032, CELLSIG_05=1C, DF405_01=9.685754776000977e-05, DF405_02=-0.00013828277587890625, DF405_03=0.00025022029876708984, DF405_04=-0.0004748106002807617, DF405_05=0.0002606511116027832, DF406_01=3.0547380447387695e-07, DF406_02=-2.3702159523963928e-07, DF406_03=-2.798624336719513e-07, DF406_04=1.2898817658424377e-07, DF406_05=-3.0780211091041565e-07, DF407_01=1, DF407_02=1, DF407_03=1, DF407_04=1, DF407_05=1, DF420_01=0, DF420_02=0, DF420_03=0, DF420_04=0, DF420_05=0, DF408_01=48.375, DF408_02=45.1875, DF408_03=45.8125, DF408_04=44.25, DF408_05=47.0625, DF404_01=-0.2003, DF404_02=-0.0838, DF404_03=-0.264, DF404_04=-0.0135, DF404_05=0.35050000000000003)>
RTCM Message: <RTCM(1077, DF002=1077, DF003=1234, DF004=368648000, DF393=0, DF409=0, DF001_7=0, DF411=0, DF412=0, DF417=0, DF418=0, DF394=9232537570078883840, NSat=5, DF395=1073741824, NSig=1, DF396=31, NCell=5, PRN_01=001, PRN_02=011, PRN_03=017, PRN_04=020, PRN_05=032, DF397_01=77, DF397_02=81, DF397_03=82, DF397_04=76, DF397_05=79, ExtSatInfo_01=0, ExtSatInfo_02=0, ExtSatInfo_03=0, ExtSatInfo_04=0, ExtSatInfo_05=0, DF398_01=0.796875, DF398_02=0.93359375, DF398_03=0.818359375, DF398_04=0.076171875, DF398_05=0.740234375, DF399_01=-1327, DF399_02=-1022, DF399_03=-1873, DF399_04=-1568, DF399_05=-1206, CELLPRN_01=001, CELLSIG_01=1C, CELLPRN_02=011, CELLSIG_02=1C, CELLPRN_03=017, CELLSIG_03=1C, CELLPRN_04=020, CELLSIG_04=1C, CELLPRN_05=032, CELLSIG_05=1C, DF405_01=-0.00043022632598876953, DF405_02=0.00036466121673583984, DF405_03=-0.00014799833297729492, DF405_04=0.00015616416931152344, DF405_05=0.0001544356346130371, DF406_01=-2.323649823665619e-07, DF406_02=-1.471489667892456e-07, DF406_03=1.1175870895385742e-07, DF406_04=-2.882443368434906e-07, DF406_05=-5.727633833885193e-08, DF407_01=2, DF407_02=2, DF407_03=2, DF407_04=2, DF407_05=2, DF420_01=0, DF420_02=0, DF420_03=0, DF420_04=0, DF420_05=0, DF408_01=48.375, DF408_02=46.125, DF408_03=46.0625, DF408_04=44.8125, DF408_05=47.0625, DF404_01=0.034, DF404_02=-0.10360000000000001, DF404_03=0.0258, DF404_04=0.465, DF404_05=-0.1259)>
RTCM Message: <RTCM(1077, DF002=1077, DF003=1234, DF004=368649000, DF393=0, DF409=0, DF001_7=0, DF411=0, DF412=0, DF417=0, DF418=0, DF394=9232537570078883840, NSat=5, DF395=1073741824, NSig=1, DF396=31, NCell=5, PRN_01=001, PRN_02=011, PRN_03=017, PRN_04=020, PRN_05=032, DF397_01=77, DF397_02=81, DF397_03=82, DF397_04=76, DF397_05=79, ExtSatInfo_01=0, ExtSatInfo_02=0, ExtSatInfo_03=0, ExtSatInfo_04=0, ExtSatInfo_05=0, DF398_01=0.7919921875, DF398_02=0.9306640625, DF398_03=0.8115234375, DF398_04=0.0712890625, DF398_05=0.736328125, DF399_01=-1328, DF399_02=-1024, DF399_03=-1875, DF399_04=-1569, DF399_05=-1207, CELLPRN_01=001, CELLSIG_01=1C, CELLPRN_02=011, CELLSIG_02=1C, CELLPRN_03=017, CELLSIG_03=1C, CELLPRN_04=020, CELLSIG_04=1C, CELLPRN_05=032, CELLSIG_05=1C, DF405_01=3.6716461181640625e-05, DF405_02=-0.0001137852668762207, DF405_03=0.00043594837188720703, DF405_04=-0.00019210577011108398, DF405_05=2.276897430419922e-05, DF406_01=6.28642737865448e-08, DF406_02=8.149072527885437e-08, DF406_03=1.564621925354004e-07, DF406_04=1.0058283805847168e-07, DF406_05=-3.4458935260772705e-08, DF407_01=3, DF407_02=3, DF407_03=3, DF407_04=3, DF407_05=3, DF420_01=0, DF420_02=0, DF420_03=0, DF420_04=0, DF420_05=0, DF408_01=48.5, DF408_02=45.8125, DF408_03=46.0, DF408_04=44.9375, DF408_05=47.375, DF404_01=-0.0109, DF404_02=0.30720000000000003, DF404_03=0.12140000000000001, DF404_04=0.07390000000000001, DF404_05=-0.4899)>
RTCM Message: <RTCM(1019, DF002=1019, DF009=1, DF076=710, DF077=0, DF078=1, DF079=1.0618350643198937e-10, DF071=11, DF081=374400, DF082=0.0, DF083=3.410605131648481e-12, DF084=1.3121869415044785e-05, DF085=11, DF086=11.65625, DF087=1.4932766134734266e-09, DF088=0.9255710016004741, DF089=6.370246410369873e-07, DF090=0.00170298689045012, DF091=1.0170042514801025e-05, DF092=5153.699285507202, DF093=374400, DF094=-3.725290298461914e-08, DF095=-0.14744636742398143, DF096=2.9802322387695312e-08, DF097=0.30571883637458086, DF098=182.375, DF099=0.1000293861143291, DF100=-2.5420376914553344e-09, DF101=8.381903171539307e-09, DF102=0, DF103=0, DF137=0)>
RTCM Message: <RTCM(1019, DF002=1019, DF009=11, DF076=710, DF077=0, DF078=1, DF079=8.265033102361485e-11, DF071=23, DF081=374400, DF082=0.0, DF083=-3.637978807091713e-12, DF084=-0.00036899372935295105, DF085=23, DF086=-16.03125, DF087=1.94938820641255e-09, DF088=0.805243568494916, DF089=-9.51811671257019e-07, DF090=0.013865918037481606, DF091=1.0419636964797974e-05, DF092=5153.68804359436, DF093=374400, DF094=6.891787052154541e-08, DF095=-0.2406930923461914, DF096=-1.471489667892456e-07, DF097=0.28292631451040506, DF098=136.46875, DF099=0.3675759476609528, DF100=-2.709725777094718e-09, DF101=-1.1641532182693481e-08, DF102=0, DF103=0, DF137=0)>
RTCM Message: <RTCM(1019, DF002=1019, DF009=17, DF076=710, DF077=0, DF078=1, DF079=-4.433786671143025e-12, DF071=51, DF081=374400, DF082=0.0, DF083=-3.979039320256561e-12, DF084=3.3434946089982986e-05, DF085=51, DF086=-89.75, DF087=1.4347278920467943e-09, DF088=-0.38748728623613715, DF089=-4.474073648452759e-06, DF090=0.008297761552967131, DF091=8.987262845039368e-06, DF092=5153.6119022369385, DF093=374400, DF094=1.6391277313232422e-07, DF095=-0.4685374484397471, DF096=1.2293457984924316e-07, DF097=0.30708272382616997, DF098=206.5625, DF099=-0.7009897669777274, DF100=-2.5610233933548443e-09, DF101=-1.0244548320770264e-08, DF102=0, DF103=0, DF137=0)>
RTCM Message: <RTCM(1019, DF002=1019, DF009=20, DF076=710, DF077=0, DF078=1, DF079=-4.6838977141305804e-11, DF071=27, DF081=374400, DF082=0.0, DF083=1.8189894035458565e-12, DF084=9.131105616688728e-05, DF085=27, DF086=16.65625, DF087=1.7978436517296359e-09, DF088=0.26628841180354357, DF089=8.326023817062378e-07, DF090=0.005512800998985767, DF091=6.329268217086792e-06, DF092=5153.763521194458, DF093=374400, DF094=-8.940696716308594e-08, DF095=0.1690492695197463, DF096=2.7939677238464355e-08, DF097=0.2955873617902398, DF098=240.375, DF099=0.4128501187078655, DF100=-2.769866114249453e-09, DF101=-7.916241884231567e-09, DF102=0, DF103=0, DF137=0)>
RTCM Message: <RTCM(1019, DF002=1019, DF009=32, DF076=710, DF077=0, DF078=1, DF079=-7.526068657170981e-11, DF071=35, DF081=374400, DF082=0.0, DF083=-2.6147972675971687e-12, DF084=-0.0005480200052261353, DF085=35, DF086=14.5, DF087=1.585817699378822e-09, DF088=0.9003039402887225, DF089=7.078051567077637e-07, DF090=0.011573668685741723, DF091=6.686896085739136e-06, DF092=5153.7204875946045, DF093=374400, DF094=-1.564621925354004e-07, DF095=0.21318546682596207, DF096=1.695007085800171e-07, DF097=0.3023187732324004, DF098=243.8125, DF099=-0.12013805005699396, DF100=-2.5914914658642374e-09, DF101=-3.259629011154175e-09, DF102=0, DF103=0, DF137=0)>
RTCM Message: <RTCM(1077, DF002=1077, DF003=1234, DF004=368650000, DF393=0, DF409=0, DF001_7=0, DF411=0, DF412=0, DF417=0, DF418=0, DF394=9232537570078883840, NSat=5, DF395=1073741824, NSig=1, DF396=31, NCell=5, PRN_01=001, PRN_02=011, PRN_03=017, PRN_04=020, PRN_05=032, DF397_01=77, DF397_02=81, DF397_03=82, DF397_04=76, DF397_05=79, ExtSatInfo_01=0, ExtSatInfo_02=0, ExtSatInfo_03=0, ExtSatInfo_04=0, ExtSatInfo_05=0, DF398_01=0.7880859375, DF398_02=0.9267578125, DF398_03=0.8056640625, DF398_04=0.0654296875, DF398_05=0.732421875, DF399_01=-1329, DF399_02=-1025, DF399_03=-1875, DF399_04=-1570, DF399_05=-1210, CELLPRN_01=001, CELLSIG_01=1C, CELLPRN_02=011, CELLSIG_02=1C, CELLPRN_03=017, CELLSIG_03=1C, CELLPRN_04=020, CELLSIG_04=1C, CELLPRN_05=032, CELLSIG_05=1C, DF405_01=-0.0004648566246032715, DF405_02=0.00037479400634765625, DF405_03=4.172325134277344e-05, DF405_04=0.00042700767517089844, DF405_05=-0.0001016855239868164, DF406_01=-9.918585419654846e-08, DF406_02=-1.862645149230957e-07, DF406_03=-1.4156103134155273e-07, DF406_04=5.587935447692871e-09, DF406_05=-2.644956111907959e-07, DF407_01=4, DF407_02=4, DF407_03=4, DF407_04=4, DF407_05=4, DF420_01=0, DF420_02=0, DF420_03=0, DF420_04=0, DF420_05=0, DF408_01=48.75, DF408_02=46.0625, DF408_03=45.125, DF408_04=44.6875, DF408_05=47.3125, DF404_01=-0.0345, DF404_02=0.008400000000000001, DF404_03=-0.1419, DF404_04=-0.4602, DF404_05=0.49920000000000003)>
RTCM Message: <RTCM(1077, DF002=1077, DF003=1234, DF004=368651000, DF393=0, DF409=0, DF001_7=0, DF411=0, DF412=0, DF417=0, DF418=0, DF394=9232537570078883840, NSat=5, DF395=1073741824, NSig=1, DF396=31, NCell=5, PRN_01=001, PRN_02=011, PRN_03=017, PRN_04=020, PRN_05=032, DF397_01=77, DF397_02=81, DF397_03=82, DF397_04=76, DF397_05=79, ExtSatInfo_01=0, ExtSatInfo_02=0, ExtSatInfo_03=0, ExtSatInfo_04=0, ExtSatInfo_05=0, DF398_01=0.783203125, DF398_02=0.923828125, DF398_03=0.7998046875, DF398_04=0.060546875, DF398_05=0.728515625, DF399_01=-1330, DF399_02=-1026, DF399_03=-1877, DF399_04=-1571, DF399_05=-1211, CELLPRN_01=001, CELLSIG_01=1C, CELLPRN_02=011, CELLSIG_02=1C, CELLPRN_03=017, CELLSIG_03=1C, CELLPRN_04=020, CELLSIG_04=1C, CELLPRN_05=032, CELLSIG_05=1C, DF405_01=-1.3530254364013672e-05, DF405_02=-0.00010961294174194336, DF405_03=-0.00035387277603149414, DF405_04=7.730722427368164e-05, DF405_05=-0.00022739171981811523, DF406_01=-5.681067705154419e-08, DF406_02=3.14321368932724e-07, DF406_03=1.685693860054016e-07, DF406_04=8.521601557731628e-08, DF406_05=-9.033828973770142e-08, DF407_01=5, DF407_02=5, DF407_03=5, DF407_04=5, DF407_05=5, DF420_01=0, DF420_02=0, DF420_03=0, DF420_04=0, DF420_05=0, DF408_01=48.375, DF408_02=45.5, DF408_03=45.625, DF408_04=44.5, DF408_05=47.25, DF404_01=-0.46440000000000003, DF404_02=0.1369, DF404_03=0.00030000000000000003, DF404_04=0.0396, DF404_05=-0.049600000000000005)>
RTCM Message: <RTCM(1077, DF002=1077, DF003=1234, DF004=368652000, DF393=0, DF409=0, DF001_7=0, DF411=0, DF412=0, DF417=0, DF418=0, DF394=9232537570078883840, NSat=5, DF395=1073741824, NSig=1, DF396=31, NCell=5, PRN_01=001, PRN_02=011, PRN_03=017, PRN_04=020, PRN_05=032, DF397_01=77, DF397_02=81, DF397_03=82, DF397_04=76, DF397_05=79, ExtSatInfo_01=0, ExtSatInfo_02=0, ExtSatInfo_03=0, ExtSatInfo_04=0, ExtSatInfo_05=0, DF398_01=0.7783203125, DF398_02=0.919921875, DF398_03=0.79296875, DF398_04=0.0556640625, DF398_05=0.724609375, DF399_01=-1332, DF399_02=-1027, DF399_03=-1877, DF399_04=-1573, DF399_05=-1211, CELLPRN_01=001, CELLSIG_01=1C, CELLPRN_02=011, CELLSIG_02=1C, CELLPRN_03=017, CELLSIG_03=1C, CELLPRN_04=020, CELLSIG_04=1C, CELLPRN_05=032, CELLSIG_05=1C, DF405_01=0.00039643049240112305, DF405_02=0.00038063526153564453, DF405_03=0.0002104043960571289, DF405_04=-0.00028389692306518555, DF405_05=-0.0003624558448791504, DF406_01=-2.491287887096405e-07, DF406_02=1.9371509552001953e-07, DF406_03=5.122274160385132e-09, DF406_04=-1.1734664440155029e-07, DF406_05=-2.728775143623352e-07, DF407_01=6, DF407_02=6, DF407_03=6, DF407_04=6, DF407_05=6, DF420_01=0, DF420_02=0, DF420_03=0, DF420_04=0, DF420_05=0, DF408_01=48.4375, DF408_02=45.9375, DF408_03=45.3125, DF408_04=44.625, DF408_05=46.875, DF404_01=0.2742, DF404_02=-0.0645, DF404_03=-0.17270000000000002, DF404_04=0.4113, DF404_05=0.1022)>
RTCM Message: <RTCM(1077, DF002=1077, DF003=1234, DF004=368653000, DF393=0, DF409=0, DF001_7=0, DF411=0, DF412=0, DF417=0, DF418=0, DF394=9232537570078883840, NSat=5, DF395=1073741824, NSig=1, DF396=31, NCell=5, PRN_01=001, PRN_02=011, PRN_03=017, PRN_04=020, PRN_05=032, DF397_01=77, DF397_02=81, DF397_03=82, DF397_04=76, DF397_05=79, ExtSatInfo_01=0, ExtSatInfo_02=0, ExtSatInfo_03=0, ExtSatInfo_04=0, ExtSatInfo_05=0, DF398_01=0.7744140625, DF398_02=0.9169921875, DF398_03=0.787109375, DF398_04=0.0498046875, DF398_05=0.7197265625, DF399_01=-1333, DF399_02=-1028, DF399_03=-1879, DF399_04=-1573, DF399_05=-1213, CELLPRN_01=001, CELLSIG_01=1C, CELLPRN_02=011, CELLSIG_02=1C, CELLPRN_03=017, CELLSIG_03=1C, CELLPRN_04=020, CELLSIG_04=1C, CELLPRN_05=032, CELLSIG_05=1C, DF405_01=-0.00015276670455932617, DF405_02=-0.00011986494064331055, DF405_03=-0.0001946091651916504, DF405_04=0.00032389163970947266, DF405_05=0.0004792213439941406, DF406_01=3.119930624961853e-07, DF406_02=1.6111880540847778e-07, DF406_03=8.009374141693115e-08, DF406_04=-2.1886080503463745e-07, DF406_05=1.94646418094635e-07, DF407_01=7, DF407_02=7, DF407_03=7, DF407_04=7, DF407_05=7, DF420_01=0, DF420_02=0, DF420_03=0, DF420_04=0, DF420_05=0, DF408_01=49.3125, DF408_02=45.875, DF408_03=45.1875, DF408_04=44.3125, DF408_05=47.25, DF404_01=0.37060000000000004, DF404_02=0.1159, DF404_03=0.2995, DF404_04=-0.21450000000000002, DF404_05=-0.3623)>
RTCM Message: <RTCM(1077, DF002=1077, DF003=1234, DF004=368654000, DF393=0, DF409=0, DF001_7=0, DF411=0, DF412=0, DF417=0, DF418=0, DF394=9232537570078883840, NSat=5, DF395=1073741824, NSig=1, DF396=31, NCell=5, PRN_01=001, PRN_02=011, PRN_03=017, PRN_04=020, PRN_05=032, DF397_01=77, DF397_02=81, DF397_03=82, DF397_04=76, DF397_05=79, ExtSatInfo_01=0, ExtSatInfo_02=0, ExtSatInfo_03=0, ExtSatInfo_04=0, ExtSatInfo_05=0, DF398_01=0.76953125, DF398_02=0.9130859375, DF398_03=0.7802734375, DF398_04=0.044921875, DF398_05=0.7158203125, DF399_01=-1335, DF399_02=-1030, DF399_03=-1880, DF399_04=-1574, DF399_05=-1215, CELLPRN_01=001, CELLSIG_01=1C, CELLPRN_02=011, CELLSIG_02=1C, CELLPRN_03=017, CELLSIG_03=1C, CELLPRN_04=020, CELLSIG_04=1C, CELLPRN_05=032, CELLSIG_05=1C, DF405_01=0.0002853274345397949, DF405_02=0.0003501772880554199, DF405_03=0.00037425756454467773, DF405_04=-4.500150680541992e-05, DF405_05=0.0003355741500854492, DF406_01=1.6111880540847778e-07, DF406_02=-2.9336661100387573e-08, DF406_03=1.5692785382270813e-07, DF406_04=2.1373853087425232e-07, DF406_05=-1.6996636986732483e-07, DF407_01=8, DF407_02=8, DF407_03=8, DF407_04=8, DF407_05=8, DF420_01=0, DF420_02=0, DF420_03=0, DF420_04=0, DF420_05=0, DF408_01=48.5, DF408_02=45.875, DF408_03=44.875, DF408_04=44.125, DF408_05=46.4375, DF404_01=0.3905, DF404_02=-0.4813, DF404_03=-0.3003, DF404_04=-0.1897, DF404_05=0.0815)>
RTCM Message: <RTCM(1019, DF002=1019, DF009=1, DF076=710, DF077=0, DF078=1, DF079=1.0618350643198937e-10, DF071=11, DF081=374400, DF082=0.0, DF083=3.410605131648481e-12, DF084=1.3121869415044785e-05, DF085=11, DF086=11.65625, DF087=1.4932766134734266e-09, DF088=0.9255710016004741, DF089=6.370246410369873e-07, DF090=0.00170298689045012, DF091=1.0170042514801025e-05, DF092=5153.699285507202, DF093=374400, DF094=-3.725290298461914e-08, DF095=-0.14744636742398143, DF096=2.9802322387695312e-08, DF097=0.30571883637458086, DF098=182.375, DF099=0.1000293861143291, DF100=-2.5420376914553344e-09, DF101=8.381903171539307e-09, DF102=0, DF103=0, DF137=0)>
RTCM Message: <RTCM(1019, DF002=1019, DF009=11, DF076=710, DF077=0, DF078=1, DF079=8.265033102361485e-11, DF071=23, DF081=374400, DF082=0.0, DF083=-3.637978807091713e-12, DF084=-0.00036899372935295105, DF085=23, DF086=-16.03125, DF087=1.94938820641255e-09, DF088=0.805243568494916, DF089=-9.51811671257019e-07, DF090=0.013865918037481606, DF091=1.0419636964797974e-05, DF092=5153.68804359436, DF093=374400, DF094=6.891787052154541e-08, DF095=-0.2406930923461914, DF096=-1.471489667892456e-07, DF097=0.28292631451040506, DF098=136.46875, DF099=0.3675759476609528, DF100=-2.709725777094718e-09, DF101=-1.1641532182693481e-08, DF102=0, DF103=0, DF137=0)>
RTCM Message: <RTCM(1019, DF002=1019, DF009=17, DF076=710, DF077=0, DF078=1, DF079=-4.433786671143025e-12, DF071=51, DF081=374400, DF082=0.0, DF083=-3.979039320256561e-12, DF084=3.3434946089982986e-05, DF085=51, DF086=-89.75, DF087=1.4347278920467943e-09, DF088=-0.38748728623613715, DF089=-4.474073648452759e-06, DF090=0.008297761552967131, DF091=8.987262845039368e-06, DF092=5153.6119022369385, DF093=374400, DF094=1.6391277313232422e-07, DF095=-0.4685374484397471, DF096=1.2293457984924316e-07, DF097=0.30708272382616997, DF098=206.5625, DF099=-0.7009897669777274, DF100=-2.5610233933548443e-09, DF101=-1.0244548320770264e-08, DF102=0, DF103=0, DF137=0)>
RTCM Message: <RTCM(1019, DF002=1019, DF009=20, DF076=710, DF077=0, DF078=1, DF079=-4.6838977141305804e-11, DF071=27, DF081=374400, DF082=0.0, DF083=1.8189894035458565e-12, DF084=9.131105616688728e-05, DF085=27, DF086=16.65625, DF087=1.7978436517296359e-09, DF088=0.26628841180354357, DF089=8.326023817062378e-07, DF090=0.005512800998985767, DF091=6.329268217086792e-06, DF092=5153.763521194458, DF093=374400, DF094=-8.940696716308594e-08, DF095=0.1690492695197463, DF096=2.7939677238464355e-08, DF097=0.2955873617902398, DF098=240.375, DF099=0.4128501187078655, DF100=-2.769866114249453e-09, DF101=-7.916241884231567e-09, DF102=0, DF103=0, DF137=0)>

My Question:
1.Why is RTK Navi not able to process the RTCM data correctly and output the NMEA messages as expected?
Additional Information:
1.I’m using RTKLib by cloning this https://github.com/rtklibexplorer/RTKLIB repository and build code for linux.
2.The RTCM data is being sent over TCP in real-time to the software.
3.The rover is in single positioning mode.

Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour], which emphasizes the importance of asking One question per Question. Providing a numbered list of questions will generally result in Question closure  Please [Edit] the Question to ask one question.
